# How to apply 2 background-color rules (parent & child) for <li> in custom accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-color

Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/15/)

The above jsFiddle has a `li` element with class name of `accordion` which we will call the ***parent element***.  Upon selecting that using jQuery, a custom `background-color` of `green` is applied.

However, I also need a **child element**, the anchors `li` element to be exact, to have the color `teal` as well when jQuery applies class name `active` to it during the initial selection ***of that specific anchor***.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="tabs">

   <li class="accordion"><a href="#tab1">Boo1</a>

      <ul id="sub-nav">
         <li><a href="#"> Ipsum Text</a></li>
         <li><a> Lorem text</a></li>
         <li><a> More lorem text </a></li>
         <li><a> Dolor Sit Amet </a></li>
      </ul>                                   

  </li>

  <li><a href="#tab2">Boo2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Boo3</a></li>
  <li class="last-item"><a href="#tab4">Boo4</a></li>

</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tabs li.active { background: green; }
.tabs li {font-size:20px;}
#sub-nav li {font-size:16px; margin-left:20px;}
#sub-nav li a.active {background:teal;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
(function(){

    $('.tabs li').on('click', function(e){
        $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).closest('ul').closest('li').children('a').addClass('active');
    })       

}());
```

Comment: select the anchor tags of the subs means?

Comment: check out the fiddle @muthu. As I said, difficult to explain in words

Comment: You should explain clearly your problem and report significant code directly in your question

Comment: @LorenzoC, I find it difficult selecting the anchor tags in of the BOO1 in the fiddle above. That's exactly what I mean sorry don't really understand english

Comment: Do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/16/

Comment: Not sure I understood the question. But I think you're looking for the contents() fonction: [jquery-docs](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

Comment: @muthu this is what I did, and I want it to basically work like this -> jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/10 but this time, I want to select the "a" elements of the sub navs and still maintaining the li selection of the main elements.I think I explain better now. Can you help?

Comment: @arttronics i've removed my answer, you're right.

Comment: @Joe Paul, I think u want this http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/20/. Please explain briefly.

Comment: Based on muthu's jsFiddle above, here is a [**working jsFiddle solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/psQSu/) for what the ***ex-stackoverflow*** member was trying to do. Having said that, please make an Answer muthu and I will Upvote you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JR6UD/) what you want? `$("ul li a", $(this))` is "the anchor tags of the subs".

Comment: not really. What I'm trying to achieve is say if ipsum is clicked, only the ipsum (it's anchor tag) and the parent list (boo1) will be selected. and of course style differently in css. which is giving me a tough time to achieve

Comment: lol this is what I did, and I want it to basically work like this -> jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/10  but this time,  I want to select the "a" elements of the sub navs and still maintaining the li selection of the main elements.I think I explain better now. Can you help?

Comment: OK. Here's 2 versions: [binds event to `li` and selects `a`](http://jsfiddle.net/4QeMU/) and [binds event to `a`](http://jsfiddle.net/b6K9A/). I hope there's what you want.